# Android:How to update new API levels in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

In Eclipse(Helios) I am getting the android API level upto 13(Android 3.2) only. I want to create a project in Android 4.0, but when I create a new project, I am getting the target API level upto 13 only. I had updated the ADT and SDK Platform tools to latest version. Even in the AVD manager, when I create a new AVD, target version appears upto API level 13 only.

Comment: Select android sdk manager.It gives package name,api.you can install the new api levels from there

Comment: Which version of ADT plugin are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to select in eclipse windows mwnu and select Android SDK Manager and it check which API level is not install and select API level that you want to install and then install packages and accept all terms and conditions and install new API.

Comment: thanks, Its showing new API levels now.It took sometime to display the API levels in my Android SDK manager.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Android SDK Manager either by clicking it's icon (a green download icon right under Eclipse' drop down menu) or by running:
ANDROID_SDK_FOLDER\tools\android.bat

And install more SDK platforms